# Native Extension Error After Installing Git & Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I've been searching for a solution since yesterday and everything I've tried leads to a dead end.

New to RoR and walking through tutorials. Everything was working fine, until I started setting up GIT and Heroku. I had to install jruby_windows and heroku-toolbelt, and I believe this botched things up.

Now when I run `bundle install` I receive the following output errors

```
\BookReview>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies........
Using rake 11.2.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.9.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using nokogiri 1.6.8
Using rack 1.6.4
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 6.0.3
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using bcrypt 3.1.11
Using bcrypt-ruby 3.0.1
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using sass 3.4.22
Using bundler 1.12.5
Installing byebug 9.0.5 with native extensions
C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:39: warning: Tempfile#unlink or delete called on open file; ignoring

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/bin/jruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160621-9244-az7xx.rb extconf.rb
NotImplementedError: C extensions are not supported
    <top> at C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:940
   (root) at C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
    <top> at extconf.rb:1

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/byebug-9.0.5 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.2.0/byebug-9.0.5/gem_make.out
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using mimemagic 0.3.0
Installing mysql2 0.4.4 with native extensions
C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:39: warning: Tempfile#unlink or delete called on open file; ignoring

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/bin/jruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160621-9244-13ylh37.rb extconf.rb
NotImplementedError: C extensions are not supported
    <top> at C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:940
   (root) at C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
    <top> at extconf.rb:2

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/mysql2-0.4.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.2.0/mysql2-0.4.4/gem_make.out
Using raty_ratings 1.2.0
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using rdoc 4.2.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using warden 1.2.6
Using mime-types 3.1
Using autoprefixer-rails 6.3.6.2
Using uglifier 3.0.0
Installing binding_of_caller 0.7.2 with native extensions
C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:39: warning: Tempfile#unlink or delete called on open file; ignoring

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/bin/jruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160621-9244-wni27b.rb extconf.rb
NotImplementedError: C extensions are not supported
    <top> at C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:940
   (root) at C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
    <top> at extconf.rb:19

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.2.0/binding_of_caller-0.7.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing byebug (9.0.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '9.0.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Anyone have any ideas to help?

Comment: can you tell me what you get when you run `ruby -v` and `rails -v` ?

Comment: `ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x64-mingw32]` and `rails 4.2.6`

Comment: try commenting out `byebug 9.0.5'` from your gem file and then try `bundle install`

Comment: I tried that, but it stops at MySQL. Just did it again and this is the output. (summarized)

`Installing mysql2 0.4.4 with native extensions
C:/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:39: warning: Tempfile#unlink or delete called on open file; ignoring

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
  
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.4'` succeeds before bundling.`

Answer (score 1):

This probably isnt an official fix. I gave up on trying different things, so I ended up reinstalling by using the railsinstaller. After setting things up again I am able to `bundle install` with no errors.